# Why does WAITFOR (RECEIVE FROM QUEUE) show up in the monitor incorrectly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I kick off the following command in my app:

```
WAITFOR (RECEIVE CONVERT(int, message_body) AS Message FROM MyQueue)
```

When I run `sp_who2 active', I get Status=SUSPENDED and Command=DELETE

[image]

Note: moved from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because is a DELETE. RECEIVe is just syntactic sugar for something like

```
DELETE from queue
OUTPUT DELETED.*
WHERE status = <receivable>;
```

If you enable retention then is an UPDATE, and will show as an UPDATE. There are some details, like how conversation group locking is done, how the proper message ExactlyOnceInOrder semantics are ensured and the syntax tree of RECEIVE is not truly possible to be built in T-SQL. As I said, details...

Is no coincidence I recommend in [Using Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) to use the OUTPUT clause of DELETE to 'dequeue' from a table...

Comment: Thanks.  Why does the status show as `SUSPENDED`?

Comment: Because is waiting for messages. I assume is a WAITFOR(RECEIVE).